# How to access to widget class from another dialog class

Tags: c++, qt, class, user-interface, qt5

Firstly, I have two classes.
The First class called `Widget`, and the second class called `addItem`.
The `Widget` class is the `main class(main window)` of application ui, but the `addItem` class is just window, appears when click on add person to add new contact.
Also the `Widget` class has a child element called `tableWidget`  .

[image]

Now I'm in `addItem` class,  **How to access to `tableWidget` element that is a child followed to `Widget` class?**

**Widget Class (.h)**

```
namespace Ui {
    class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);

private slots:
    void on_delete_btn_clicked();   
    void on_add_btn_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};
```

**addItem Class (.h)**

```
namespace Ui {
    class addItem;
}

class addItem : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit addItem(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~addItem();

private slots:
    void on_addBtn_clicked();

private:
    Ui::addItem *ui;
};
```

---

## Edit

The following method belong to `addItem` class.

[image]

**addItem.cpp:**

```
void addItem::on_addBtn_clicked(){
    emit mySignal(ui->name_txt->text(), ui->address_txt->text(), ui->phoneNum_txt->text(), ui->mobileNum_txt->text());
    Widget *widget = new Widget;
    connect(this, SIGNAL(mySignal(QString,QString,QString,QString)), widget, SLOT(addMyItem(QString,QString,QString,QString)));
    this->close();
}
```

See also the rest of the code that I wrote :

**addItem.h:**

```
signals:
    void mySignal(QString, QString, QString, QString);
```

**Widget.h** (mainwindow):

```
private slots:
    void addMyItem(QString, QString, QString, QString);
```

**Widget.cpp** (mainwindow):

```
void Widget::addMyItem(QString name, QString address, QString phone_number, QString mobile_number){
    qDebug() << name << "\n" << address << "\n" << phone_number << "\n" << mobile_number;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting

```
public:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
```

isn't good practice, so you can use getters and setters.

For example, if you want take text from `QTableWidget`, provide method for example

```
QString Widget::getCellData(int row, int col)
{
    return ui->tableWidget->item(row,col)->text();
}
```

To set data:

```
void Widget::setCellData(int row, int col, QString txt)
{
    //create item if you need
    ui->tableWidget->item(row,col)->setText(txt);
}
```

and so on. I hope you will understand main idea and how to do it.

But you can use also signals and slots:

For example user clicks on add button and you want add new data in table, then emit from addItem button signal:

```
 emit mySignal(name, address, phone , mobile);
```

where name is `ui->nameLineEdit->text()` and so on. Just take text from lineEdit and send it.

Catch it with special slot in `Widget` class. In this slot you can create new row and set data.

```
void Widget::mySlot(QString name,QString address,QString phone ,QString mobile)
{
    //create cells and set data in it
}
```

And of course you should connect `mySignal` from `addItem` class to `mySlot` in `Widget` class.

```
addItem *mDialog = new addItem;
connect(mDialog,SIGNAL(mySignal(QString,QString,QString,QString)),this,SLOT(mySlot(QString,QString,QString,QString)));
```

Conclusion: I think, you should use signals and slots.

---

### Edit

Explanation in detail:

You have Dialog class and mainwindow:

dialog.h:

```
signals:
    void mySignal(QString,QString,QString,QString);
```

dialog.cpp When user clicks we get data, emit signal and close dialog.

```
void Dialog::on_addItemButton_clicked()
{
    emit mySignal(ui->lineEdit_2->text(),ui->lineEdit_3->text(),ui->lineEdit_4->text(),ui->lineEdit_5->text());
    this->close();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
private slots:
      void addMyItems(QString,QString,QString,QString);
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::addMyItems(QString name,QString address,QString phone ,QString mobile)
{
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() + 1);//increase row count by 1

    int row = ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1;

    //set all data in cells
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,0,new QTableWidgetItem(name));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,1,new QTableWidgetItem(address));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,2,new QTableWidgetItem(phone));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row,3,new QTableWidgetItem(mobile));
}
```

Slot for button in mainwindow which opens dialog:

```
void MainWindow::on_Add_clicked()
{
    Dialog *dia = new Dialog;//our dialog
    dia->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);//we don't want memory leak
    //connection
    connect(dia,SIGNAL(mySignal(QString,QString,QString,QString)),this,SLOT(addMyItems(QString,QString,QString,QString)));
    dia->setModal(true);//you can use modal window instead of exe()
    dia->show();
}
```

Result:

I clicked on Add button and get dialog:

[image]

Now I set some data and clicked Additem button:

[image]

As you can see, our connection works, data properly placed in the tableWidget.

Comment: Thanks, **For the first way** I know the setter and the getter, but why you change the `Ui::Widget *ui;` to public, and also how to access to it from `addItem` class. **For the second way** it still complex for me.

Comment: @LionKing I think that first way is wrong. I wrote that it is bad practise. But tell me please, as I understood, you call addItem window FROM widget class, right? If so, you should use second way and I can explain in details.

Comment: **About your inquiry**, yes, by this way `addItem addItemWidget; addItemWidget.exec()`;. **But there is no ways except `signal & slot` to get some data from another class?**

Comment: @LionKing I updated my answer, there is detail explanation, see it please. Moreover I added screnshots to show that all works properly.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, everything is good, but the last step when call `connect` function, I must call `connect` function after fill  fields `name`, `address`, `phone number`, `mobile number`,  after that you should click on `add button`, the add button and previous text fields is in `addItem` class. But you've called `connect` function in `mainwindow`, and you should call `connect` after fill text fields and click add button, that mean you must called in `addItem` class. **Please see my question again specifically last picture to see the order**.

Comment: @LionKing unfortunately I did not understand you problem, but I try to guess. If you want forbid user enter empty data(all lineEdits should have at least one character), then before you emit mySignal you should check does every lineEdit have text. Use lineEdit->text().isEmpty() if some kineEdit empty, don't emit signal, say to user that there is error,if all normal, then emit signal and close window

Comment: Thank you for continuing to help me, but unfortunately what I mean not what you guessed. you've called `connect` function in wrong place. **Please see my question again to see the new modification**.

Comment: @LionKing so your problem is that your slot Never called? It is Never called because you firstly emit signal and after this do connection, so when you emit signal there is no any connection, any slot. You need first of all create Widget, set connect as you wrote and AFTER this you can emit signal, in this case your signal will be catched by slot which you need. And you should show() your widget

Comment: That is good, now it is works fine, thank you, but there is an error message appear related to database `QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name`, because I have created an object of `Widget(mainwindow)` in `addItem::on_addBtn_clicked()`.

Comment: QSqlDatabase::addDatabase() is supposed to be called once per type and connection name. I suppose that in widget's constructor you did the database connection, so when you create new widget, you try to open same database few times, and you get this error. To solve this error, you shouldn't do this. Write something which will not connect to same database second time.

Comment: @LionKing Unfortunately I can't, as you know, there is extremely bad situation in my country(Ukraine), so my university works in hard mode, twice harder then before. I work a lot every day and I haven't many free time, sometimes I help others on SO and learn something new, but it is very hard, so I don't have so much free time, sorry please, but I can't, I hope that you will understand me. :(

Comment: No problem. but I'm still not understand the database problem. but I will try to solve it. thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The way I normally handle these things is quite non Qt-ish, but it makes unit testing easier. I have something like MVC (model-view-controller), but in Qt the V and C are one.

For example the model could be:

```
class Record
{
public:
  std::string mName;
  std::string mAddress;
  std::string mPhoneNumber;
  std::string mMobileNumber;
};

class Model
{
public:
  void AddRecord(std::unique_ptr<Record> rec)
  {
      mRecords.emplace_back(std::move(rec));
  }

  const Record* ItemAt(size_t index) const
  {
     if (index > mRecords.size()) { return nullptr; }
     return mRecords(index);
  }

  size_t NumRecords() const
  {
    return mRecords.size();
  }
private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Record> mRecords;
};
```

Then in your main function you can construct a model and pass it to your main/view window:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    // Create app instance
    QApplication a( argc, argv );

    Model model;
    MainWindow mainWindow(model); // MainWindow stores a reference to the model
    mainWindow.exec();
```

And the when you create the sub dialog simply pass that the model too. Or have it return a `std::unique_ptr<Record>`

```
void MainWindow::on_Add_clicked()
{
    Dialog *dia = new Dialog(this, mModel);//Where mModel is the Model instance reference we passed to Widget in main()
    dia->exec();
}
```

Its worth noting that Qt comes with its own model classes for the views. You could take your own Model class and have Qts view model auto update the UI when your view model changes. This is much more advanced though. For now you could just manually keep your model in sync with your UI, i.e if you add a record or remove a record from model, then update your table widget.

Disclaimer: I didn't actually try to compile any of this code, treat it as pesudo code ;)

Comment: Thanks, but `MVC` now can't, because my application is not been built by `MVC`.

Comment: I know, thats why I said the Qt MVC is optional, your own MVC as I have posted here can still easily be done.